# C# Runtime border around grid prevents mouse event handling

Tags: c#, mouseevent, border

I've built a canvas at runtime, and assigned event handlers to mouse operations and it worked well. I then decided I wanted a border around it so created a border which prevented the handlers from working.

What I have tried:

- I have commented out the border and the thumb objects. The canvas is drawn fine, and the event handling works.
- I then removed the attached event handlers from obj and attached the event handlers to the border events but the events only fire if you click right on the border, not inside it.
- I have tried the Preview and -Preview events on both the canvas and the border.
- attaching event handlers to both elements

obj_MouseLeftButtonDown just calls a message box so I can test everything.
Would anyone know why I can not get the events to trigger on the canvas?

```
if (sender is Canvas)
        {
            Canvas obj = new Canvas();
            obj.Name = "Container"+Objcount;
            obj.Height = 100;
            obj.Width = 100;
            obj.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(obj_MouseLeftButtonDown);
            obj.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(obj_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            obj.PreviewMouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(dragaround);

            Border Border1 = new Border();
            Border1.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
            Border1.BorderBrush = Brushes.Gray;
            Border1.Child = obj;
            desk.Children.Add(Border1);

            Thumb obj1 = new Thumb();
            obj1.Name = "Thumb" + Objcount;
            Canvas.SetRight(obj1, 0);
            Canvas.SetBottom(obj1, 0);
            obj1.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(myThumb_DragDelta);
            obj.Children.Add(obj1);
            ++Objcount;
        }
```

Comment: Probably now you should attach event handlers to BOTH border and canvas

Comment: I knew I was going to leave something out! Yes, I did attach handlers to the events for both without success, but thank you for your suggestion. It is as if the border is made of two elements and one is transparent that sits over the border element. I will continue to investigate, thank you.

Comment: try to add thumb to the desk.children, not to the canvas. If everything else fails you can always draw the border\rectangle on the canvas manually :d

Comment: Oh yes I'll try that when I'm back at my computer, thanks Gleb Sevruk but I don't hold much hope for it. Because desk is a canvas as well.  Essentially desk is a canvas I drop elements on and one element i want to be an adjustable canvas. The thumb allows this and it works without the border. I think if I send thumb to desk it'll make the desk canvas adjustable but i won't know until i try. Will update once I've tried

Comment: Perhaps i need to add it to the canvas, then assign the canvas to the border. I'm try this also.

Comment: By adding thumb to the canvas you are not able to escape parent container which is the border...

Answer (score 1):

This is odd. After trying various things, commenting out code, re-arranging it etc I shut down my computer and went out for the day. When I got back and fired it all up again I managed to get it to work. I don't know how because I am back to the original code I posted and my mouse events are clicking through. Not sure if anyone else has ever had this before but for anyone out there that is experiencing this kind of thing just try restart VS or even your computer. I'm lost for an explanation but its working now. Thank you Gleb Sevruk for the time you took to offer some additional things to try.